# Initialize 2D Array of custom objects

Tags: java, arrays

I've a question about initializing a 2D Array of custom objects.

I have 2 Objects : a `CellEntity`, and a `MapEntity` who contains:

```
private final ICellEntity[][] cellMap;
```

I've initialized `cellmap` in the `MapEntity`'s constructor

```
cellMap = new CellEntity[width][length];
```

but every `CellEntity` is `null`.

I want to know if there's a solution to invoke (to force) a method in `CellEntity` class in order to init each `CellEntity` in the `cellMap`?

Comment: What is `ICellEntity`? Is it a typo error with an extra `i` infront?

Comment: Any reason why you want to declare your `cellMap`array as final?

Comment: public class CellEntity implements ICellEntity ; CellEntity constructor needs a CellBuilder Class in order to create the Object.

I dont want to modify the cellMap it's the reason why cellMap is final.

Comment: Take a look at my solutions. If it helps, do accept the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I dont want to modify the cellMap it's the reason why cellMap is final

Since you want to make it final. You can set it's value via the constructor:

```
class MapEntity
{
    private final ICellEntity[][] cellMap;

    public MapEntity(ICellEntity[][] cellMap){
        this.cellMap = cellMap;
    }
}
```

You can create an initialized cellMap array first, then pass it via the constructor to set the cellMap's value within MapEntity.

```
//Initialize your cellMap else where first
ICellEntity[][] cellMap = new CellEntity[width][length];
for(int x=0; x<width; x++)
    for(int y=0; y<length; y++)
        cellMap[x][y] = new CellEntity();

//Pass in the initialized cellMap via the constructor
MapEntity mapEntity = new MapEntity(cellMap);
```

> I want to know if there's a solution to invoke (to force) a method in CellEntity class in order to init each CellEntity in the cellMap?

Well, if your `cellMap` was declared as final, there is no way you can set it via a method (accessor), other than probably using reflection *(which I don't think you will like it very much)*.

Answer (score 0):

```
cellMap = new CellEntity[width][length];
for(int i = 0; i < width; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < length; j++){
        cellMap[i][j] = new CellEntity(); //do constructor-y stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the only one solution ? There's no way to implements this method on CellEntity Class ?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know if there's a solution to invoke (to force) a method in CellEntity class in order to init each CellEntity in the cellMap?

It is actually possible, but the array has to be created first.

## First variation

Create array in constructor first. We **cannot change the reference** of cellMap after creation, but we still can assign the values within it:

```
class TestRunner{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MapEntity me = new MapEntity(5, 5);
        me.initCellMap();   //init cellMap separately
    }
}

class MapEntity
{
    private final CellEntity[][] cellMap;

    public MapEntity(int width, int length){
        cellMap = new CellEntity[width][length];   //has to be done in constructor
    }

    public void initCellMap(){
        for(int x=0; x<cellMap.length; x++)
            for(int y=0; y<cellMap[0].length; y++)
                cellMap[x][y] = new CellEntity();
    }
}
```

## Second variation

Almost similar to the first, you create the array first, if you do not want to create it in the constructor (personallyy, I do not favour this approach):

```
class TestRunner{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MapEntity me = new MapEntity();
        me.initCellMap();   //init cellMap separately
    }
}

class MapEntity
{
    final int LENGTH = 5;
    final int WIDTH = 5;
    final CellEntity[][] cellMap = new CellEntity[WIDTH][LENGTH];

    public MapEntity(){     
    }

    public void initCellMap(){
        for(int x=0; x<cellMap.length; x++)
            for(int y=0; y<cellMap[0].length; y++)
                cellMap[x][y] = new CellEntity();
    }
}
```